# MATLAB curve fitting - least squares method - wrong "fit" using high degrees

Tags: matlab, least-squares, curve-fitting

Anyone here that could help me with the following problem?
The following code calculates the best polynomial fit to a given data-set, that is; a polynomial of a specified degree.

Unfortunately, whatever the data-set may be, usually at degree 6 or higher, MATLAB gets a totally wrong fit.  Usually the fit curves totally away from the data in a sort of exponantial-looking-manner downwards.  (see the example: degree = 8).

```
x=[1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5] % experimental x-values
y=[4.3 6.2 10.1 13.5 19.8 22.6 24.7 29.2] % experimental y-values

degree=8; % specify the degree
A = zeros(length(x),degree);
for exponent=0:degree;
for data=1:length(x);
   A(data,exponent+1)=x(data).^exponent; % create matrix A
end;
end;

a=inv((transpose(A)*A))*transpose(A)*y'; % a are the coëfficients of the polynom
a=flipud(a);
fitpolynoom=polyval(a,x);
error=sum((y-fitpolynoom).^2); % calculates the fit-error using the least-squares method
fitpolynoom=polyval(a,x);

figure;
plot(x,y,'black*',x,fitpolynoom,'g-');

error % displays the value of the fit-error in the Matlab command window
```

Thanks in advance.

[image: Degree 8 - wrong MATLAB polynomial curve fitting]

Answer (score 4):

First, some remarks: for least-squares fitting polynomials in Matlab, you could use the existing`polyfit` function instead. Furthermore (this may depend on your application) you probably should not be fitting $8$th degree polynomials, especially when you have $8$ data points. In this answer, I assume you have good reasons to fit polynomials to your data (e.g., just for self-study purposes).

The issue is a numeric problem arising from matrix inversion. For solving equations of type $Ax=b$ where $A$ is a square matrix, actually inverting $A$ is not recommended (See [Blogpost 'Don't invert that matrix' by John D. Cook](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/)). In the least-squares case, instead of 
\begin{equation}
a = (A^\mathrm{T} A)^{-1} A^\mathrm{T} y^\mathrm{T}
\end{equation}
it is better to solve 
\begin{equation}
(A^\mathrm{T} A)a = A^\mathrm{T} y^\mathrm{T}
\end{equation}
by other means. In your MATLAB code, you may replace

```
a=inv((transpose(A)*A))*transpose(A)*y';
```

by

```
a = (transpose(A) * A) \ (transpose(A) * y');
```

By this modification to your code, I obtained a fit going through the data points.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had no idea. Somebody else gave a solution to the problem using a different approach: 

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070670/matlab-curve-fitting-least-squares-method-wrong-fit-using-high-degrees

The fit-errors differ in both approaches however, I wonder which one of them are "most realistic"?

Perhaps one of them would also have less dramatic oscillating peaks using higher degree polynomials (which seem to occur mostly at the last (or first) elements of the data vectors, I wonder why and further more: can these oscillations not be avoided or averaged out)?

Comment: I really recommend you reading the blogpost that @JuhoKokkala posted.

Comment: I've read it. It's interesting, however it's not clear **what kind** of factorisation the author is talking about.

Further more, in the comments of the article, there is a interesting link to an interesting article stating that matrix inversion **shouldn't** be less accurate [http://arxive...](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.6035v1.pdf).

Comment: In the case of least squares, solving by performing a QR factorisation of A means that you don't have to form the matrix A'*A. This latter matrix's condition number will be the square of the condition number of A, and that will mean you will loose accuracy.